# Excluding Transitive Dependencies in Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, build-dependencies

I'm taking a look at the source of a contact merger application on F-Droid located [Here](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=contact+merger&fdid=de.measite.contactmerger)
and getting an `UNEXPECTED TOP LEVEL EXCEPTION`during compilation.

I've seen questions such as this so I know the error is from a duplicate SPIClassIterator file.  Within the source, a new `SPIClassIterator.java` was created so this makes sense.  How might I go about using `exclude` in gradle to remove the original `SPIClassIterator` class file.  Or what is the best method to avoid this?

Here is a shot of the Error Log.

```
:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added:Lorg/apache/lucene/util/SPIClassIterator;
    at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:122)
    at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:161)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:685)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:634)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$600(Main.java:78)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:572)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Below is a section of build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.tundem.aboutlibraries:library:2.0.3@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'org.ow2.asm:asm:4.0'
    compile 'com.esotericsoftware.kryo:kryo:2.24.0' 
    compile ('org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:4.7.1'){
        exclude module: 'SPIClassIterator'
    }
    compile 'org.apache.lucene:lucene-misc:4.7.1'
    compile 'org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:4.7.1'
    compile 'org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:4.7.1'
    compile 'org.apache.lucene:lucene-codecs:4.7.1'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    dexOptions {
       preDexLibraries = false
    }

    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'org/apache/lucene/util/SPIClassIterator.class'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/org.apache.lucene.codecs.PostingsFormat'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/org.apache.lucene.codecs.DocValuesFormat'
    }
```

Ive attempted using the exclude on `lucene-core` as that is the library that contains the original `SPIClassIterator` that I would like to exclude.  I appreciate the clarification.

Comment: I am looking at this project as well.  Any idea what the intention is of providing a custom implementation of SPIClassIterator.java?  I was able to eliminate this error by removing the custom source.